# Wordpress Stats Plugin: Display Post Views

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

i'm currently using latest version of jetpack. So the stats plugin is also included in this plugin. But now i want to display the number of views the single post get on the `single.php` file using the data from Stats plugin included in jetpack. So how can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try going to the plugin in the dashboard and visit the plugin site. I bet there's an instructions there on how to use the plugin (e.g. shortcodes and options)

Comment: I yanked the 'jetpack' tag because it is typically used for a different 'jetpack' project.